# Average number of rolls of die to see each side at least once

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, average

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A Question About Dice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25568/a-question-about-dice)

You have a weighted n-sided die. Every side of the die is weighted differently where side n1 has a weight of w1, n2 has a weight of w2, ...

Estimate the average number of rolls needed to see every face at least once.

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate: although that question is a special case of this one, the answers address the general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variant of the [coupon collector's problem](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/FlGaTh92.pdf)

Formula (14a) is what you need.

Updated after comments.

Comment: It's correct that this is the coupon collector's problem, but that expected number can't be right - consider the case where all of the weights are 1 (or so nearly so as to be negligibly different, while still meeting the 'weighted differently' constraint).  The formula would suggest that it takes only $n$ rolls to 'collect' all $n$ sides.

Comment: Is it still the coupon's collectors problem if the sides are weighted differently?  Meaning each side has a different probability of showing up.

Comment: @toobsco42 It's still a variant thereof, and I would start with 'weighted coupon collector's problem' as a search term - though a bit of research suggests that the problem may not have any closed-form solution.

Comment: But it can't be correct, because the original problem has $w_k=\frac{1}{n}$ and your answer would give us $n^2$ in that case, when it should be $nH_n = O(n\log n)$

Comment: Thanks.  I was thinking it was a variant.  I just thought it had a closed-form solution because I was asked to create a method in Java to help me solve this problem.

Comment: @toobsco42 Given that the question says 'estimate', I suspect what your teacher is after is a _simulation_ where you actually do the collecting and tally how many rolls it takes, over several thousand (or million) runs of the simulation...

Comment: I think this may be along the lines of what i was looking for:
http://programworlds.blogspot.com/2012/07/coupon-collector-simulation.html
But I am trying to determine the Big O complexity with the random number generator.