# Average number of tries to get an X number of unique elements

Tags: probability-distributions

Assuming that we have the following loot table

```
Type     Chance Number of unique elements 
common   30.00%  21
Uncommon 30.00%  27
Rare     20.00%  32
Ultra    15.00%  14
Epic     5.00%   10
```

How can I calculate the average number of tries to get X unique elements regardless from their rarity, with x starting from 1 to all elements (tries to get 1 element, tries to get 2 etc...). I have tried the formula [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25568/expected-number-of-rolling-a-pair-of-dice-to-generate-all-possible-sums/25576#25576) but that works only for calculating the number of tries for all elements. Ideally I want to plug the formula in excel so I can use it for different games.

P.s. I am not a math student, just a gamer!