# Expected number of rolls until lcm is greater than $2000$?

Tags: probability, number-theory, probability-theory, expected-value, gcd-and-lcm

> You continually roll a fair $10$ sided dice. What is the expected number of rolls until the lowest common multiple of all numbers that have appeared is greater than $2000$?

The primes in the numbers $1$ to $10$ are $2,3,5,7$. The lowest common multiple of these numbers  is $210$. However, different numbers could come in different frequencies (one $9$ is worth two $3$s). How can you deal with this?

I am happy for solutions with approximate answers. The true value by simluation is around $18.8$.

Comment: $9$ is not prime, but $5$ is.

Comment: @lulu corrected

Comment: $5$ is still prime.

Comment: @lulu mistake when editing

Comment: But note:  it's not just primes you need to worry about, you also have to consider the prime powers $2^3, 3^2$.

Comment: @lulu thats the next sentence

Comment: I would proceed by states. Introduce a state $(a,b,c,d)$ for the possible lcm's.  Specifically, let $(a,b,c,d)$ refer to the lcm $2^a3^b5^c7^d$, with the obvious restrictions on $a,b,c,d$

Comment: Your post says nothing about prime powers, and the lcm of $2,3,5,7$ hasn't got much to do with the problem (it's just one of the many possible states).

Comment: @lulu if I knew to do I wouldnt be asking :)

Comment: I told you what to do...introduce states for the possible lcm's and consider the expected number of turns it takes from each state.  There are a lot of possible states, so the problem is quite tedious. A lot easier if you automate the computation, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The least common multiple of all the numbers $1-10$ is $2520$. Since half of this number is less than $2000$, it follows that you need to achieve $2520$ as an lcm, which means you need to see rolls of $7, 8, 9,$ and one of either $5$ or $10$. Other rolls are irrelevant to getting $2520$ as lcm.

Let $T$ be the number of rolls it takes to see a $7, 8, 9,$ and either a $5$ or $10$. Then $T$ can be written as $$T = X_1 + X_2 + X_3 + X_4,$$ where $X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4$ are independent [geometric r.v.'s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) representing the time to get the first, second, third, and fourth of the four necessary prime factors of $2520$. $X_1$ always has a parameter of $\frac{5}{10}$, but the parameters of $X_2, X_3, X_4$ depend on whether the $5$ or $10$ has been rolled yet after the first, second, third prime factors of $2520$ have been collected.
Let $A_i$, $i = 1, 2, 3, 4$, be the event that the $5$ or $10$ is the $i$th to be achieved out of the $4$ types of roll necessary.
Then we can use [conditional expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation) to calculate $$\Bbb{E}[T] = \sum_{i=1}^4 \Bbb{E}[T | A_i] \Bbb{P}(A_i).$$ The probabilities of the $A_i$ are easy to find:
\begin{align*}
\Bbb{P}(A_1) &= \frac{2}{5}, \\
\Bbb{P}(A_2) &= \frac{3}{5} \times \frac{2}{4} = \frac{3}{10}, \\
\Bbb{P}(A_3) &= \frac{3}{5} \times \frac{2}{4} \times \frac{2}{3} = \frac{1}{5}, \\
\Bbb{P}(A_4) &= \frac{3}{5} \times \frac{2}{4} \times \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{10}. \
\end{align*}

Conditioned on the $A_i$, we also find
\begin{align*}
\Bbb{E}[T | A_1] &= \sum_{j=1}^4 \Bbb{E}[X_j | A_1] = \frac{10}{5} + \frac{10}{3} + \frac{10}{2} + \frac{10}{1} = \frac{61}{3}, \\
\Bbb{E}[T | A_2] &= \sum_{j=1}^4 \Bbb{E}[X_j | A_2] = \frac{10}{5} + \frac{10}{4} + \frac{10}{2} + \frac{10}{1} = \frac{39}{2}, \\ 
\Bbb{E}[T | A_3] &= \sum_{j=1}^4 \Bbb{E}[X_j | A_3] = \frac{10}{5} + \frac{10}{4} + \frac{10}{3} + \frac{10}{1} = \frac{107}{6}, \\
\Bbb{E}[T | A_4] &= \sum_{j=1}^4 \Bbb{E}[X_j | A_4] = \frac{10}{5} + \frac{10}{4} + \frac{10}{3} + \frac{10}{2} = \frac{77}{6}, \\ 
\end{align*}

and putting it all together,
\begin{align*}
\Bbb{E}[T] &= \sum_{i=1}^4 \Bbb{E}[T | A_i] \Bbb{P}(A_i) \\
 &= \frac{2}{5} \times \frac{61}{3} + \frac{3}{10} \times \frac{39}{2} + \frac{1}{5} \times \frac{107}{6} + \frac{1}{10} \times \frac{77}{6} \\
 &= \frac{113}{6} \approx 18.83333... \
\end{align*}

So, it should take a little less than $19$ rolls, on average, to see an lcm of $2520$.

Comment: You need either a $5$ or a $10$, not just a $5$, among your rolls

Comment: why cant you get three 2s instead of an 8?

Comment: @Trajan, the lcm of $2,2,$ and $2$ is $2$, not $8$.

Comment: @TonyK my mistake sorry

Comment: I think @RossMillikan's comment suddenly makes the problem more difficult!

Comment: @Trajan, perhaps you should unaccept it?

Comment: @TonyK i have done so

Comment: Because either a $5$ or a $10$ can supply the necessary factor $5$, instead of an abbreviated version of the coupon collector's problem this is an abbreviated version of the coupon collector's problem with unequal probabilities. [Expected number of rolling a pair of dice to generate all possible sums](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/25568/139123) may be relevant.

Comment: This solution is incorrect and should be edited or deleted. As has been remarked, it is not true that you need to see a $5$, a $10$ would suffice.

Comment: +1 for the insight that you need to observe at least one each 7, 8, 9 and 5 (or 10), even if the answer as currently written contains a mistake due to neglecting the possibility of obtaining 5 as a factor by rolling 10.

Comment: OK, I think I fixed the analysis above. My updated answer of $\frac{113}{6} \approx 18.8333...$ agrees much more closely with the OP's average from simulations.

Comment: @RiversMcForge Can you clarify how to obtain the conditioning results? In my understanding, when you calculate E[T|A1] = 10/5+10/3+10/2+10, the 10/5 allows for the probability that a 7, 8, or 9 occurs before the first (5 or 10); as such, why isn't the correct expression E[T|A1] = 7/2+10/3+10/2+10, since the first term can't be a 7, 8, or 9?

Comment: @Cyclopropane The idea is that the expected waiting time *prior* to seeing one of $\{ 5, 10 \}$ never changes under any scenario, and seeing those only increases the expected waiting times *after* they've been seen. You can also check that your way doesn't work directly from the unconditional known value of $E[X_1] = 2$: your method would give $$E[X_1 | A_1] P(A_1) + E[X_1 | A_1^c] P(A_1^c) = \frac{7}{2} * \frac{2}{5} + \frac{8}{3} * \frac{3}{5} = 3,$$ which is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

(sketch of the method)

Best to proceed by states.

We remark that $$\text{lcm}(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)=2^3\times 3^2\times 5\times 7=2520$$
is so close to $2000$ that no divisor of it will suffice.  It follows that you need to see the $8$, the $9$, the $7$ and either a $5$ or a $10$.

Introduce states $(a,b,c,d)$ according to whether or not the relevant prime power, $(2^3,3^2,5,7)$, has been fully seen.  Here $a,b,c,d\in \{0,1\}$ and, $(1,1,0,0)$, say, means that you have seen $8,9$ but none of $5,7,10$.  We remark that there are $16$ states which we can number according to the binary representations of the numbers $0,\cdots, 15$ in an obvious way.  Since $14 =1110_2$  we'd have state $14$ be $(1,1,1,0)$, meaning that you have only to see the $7$.  Similarly, the state $8=(1,0,0,0)$ would mean that you had seen the $8$ roll but sill needed the $9$, the $7$ and either the $5$ or the $10$.

Let $E_i$ be the expected number of tosses it will take given that you are starting in state $i$.  Of course, the answer to the question is $E_0$.
We see that $E_{15}=0$ since state $15$ means you have already seen enough tosses.

$E_{14}=10$ since you expect it to take $10$ tosses to see the $7$.

$E_{13}=5$ since you expect it to take $5$ tosses to see either the $5$ or the $10$.

For $E_{12}=E_{(1,1,0,0)}$ we note that $$E_{12}=\frac 7{10}\times (E_{12}+1)+\frac 2{10}\times (E_{14}+1)+\frac 1{10}\times (E_{13}+1)\implies$$ $$\implies E_{12}=\frac {35}3$$

Continue in this manner.  As you see, the computations are tedious but not difficult.  They are also a bit error prone, so I suggest simulation to confirm the result.